# How to program Nexus LED?

Tags: android

I would like to program the LED present at the bottom of Nexus 5 in my android application.
Is there any way(API) to do so?
I have looked around but haven't found any code help for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do so using the [`NotificationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) API.